# Is it possible to compose $parts in Zend_Date methods

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm not sure something like this could work or not :

```
$date = Zend_Date::now();
$date->toValue('yyyyMM');
$date->compare($date, 'yyyyMM')
```

because of compound $part 'yyyyMM'.

Is it supported ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code from above returns `201801` for 31 Jan 2018.
To get a number of month, use instead

```
$date->toValue('yyyy') * 12 + $date->toValue('MM');
```